# Graphite null json data responses, and more frequent datapoints than expected

Tags: graphite

I am having troubles interpreting the data coming back from render API on some metrics I have set up in Graphite.  I have a splunk query populating the results, and graphite is configured to poll this query which has a 1 minute range every one minute.  The results I am getting back when doing a render api call with format=json are not making much sense to me.  If I add into the api call a from=-1min, I get 2 datapoint results, 4 for -2min, etc.  Along with this, often the datapoints are just given a null value which should never happen given how populated this splunk query is when I run it manually for the same time ranges.

I am wondering if there is any additional documentation on the render api other than what is listed here: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.15/render_api.html  because it really isn't giving me much on why the data is appearing the way it is.  Does anyone know of additional docs, or have any insight into what is going on here?

Comment: can you provide content of `storage-schemas.conf` and/or output of `whisper-info.py path_to_example_metric.wsp`?

Comment: here is the output of whisper-info:

maxRetention: 94608000
xFilesFactor: 0.5
aggregationMethod: average
fileSize: 376084
Archive 0
retention: 1209600
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 20160
size: 241920
offset: 64
Archive 1
retention: 2419200
secondsPerPoint: 300
points: 8064
size: 96768
offset: 241984
Archive 2
retention: 7257600
secondsPerPoint: 3600
points: 2016
size: 24192
offset: 338752
Archive 3
retention: 94608000
secondsPerPoint: 86400
points: 1095
size: 13140
offset: 362944

Comment: I should also note, after looking at the data again, it seems based on what I am seeing, that the datapoints are displaying at 30 second intervals, even though from what I can tell everything is configured to log only at 1min intervals.  I am further convinced it is inputting correctly since every other entry in the output returned is a proper value, and the values in between are the null values.  So it seems it might perhaps be an issue with displaying the datapoints?  It happens if I try raw format as well.  I also tried noNullPoints=true but the null values were not removed.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but we are using sensu to collect the metrics as well